# Sampling Variance of Sample Proportion with a Discarded Outcome

Tags: variance, binomial-distribution, compound-distributions

#### Question:

A random experiment with three exhaustive and mutually exclusive outcomes $A, B, C$ is performed $n$ times, resulting in a sample of outcomes $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$. The following statistic is calculated:

$$Y = \frac{\sum_i \mathbb{1}_{\{X_i\in A\}}}{\sum_i \mathbb{1}_{\{X_i\in A\cup C\}}}\,.$$

> ***What is the sampling variance of $Y$?***

#### Special Case:

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ equal $P(X_1 = A), P(X_1 = B), P(X_1 = C)$ respectively. Then $\mathrm{var}(Y) = \alpha(1-\alpha)/n$ in the special case where $B = \emptyset$. Along the same lines,
$$\mathrm{var}\left(Y \;\middle|\; \sum_i \mathbb{1}_{\{X_i\in A\cup C\}} = t\right)
= \frac{\alpha\gamma}{(\alpha + \gamma)t}\,.$$

#### Search Terms

- Normal binomial compound distribution
- Sample proportion with censoring
- Sample proportion, three outcomes

---

Edit: In the special case when $X_i \in B$ for all $i$, set $Y = 0$. (Thanks @Ziddletwix). In the intended interpretation $n$ is large and $P(X_1 \in B) > 0$.

Edit: What I'm really after is a 95% confidence interval for $Y$, but I'm primarily interested in calculating the variance.

Comment: How is $Y$ defined when $X_i \in B$ for all $i$? Is it just set to be 0?

Comment: @Ziddletwix Yes; let's set $Y = 0$ when $X_i\in B \:\forall i$. In my data $n$ is large, and this event occurs with negligible frequency.